# Handle multiple checkboxes with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I currently have a basic HTML page with 2 checkboxes in it.

I have a jQuery script which, when a checkbox changes, adds or removes a class to the checkbox to display it checked or not. I can't make more than one checkbox work at once. Here is my HTML and JS:

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<div class="checkbox-field w-checkbox w-clearfix">
  <div class="checkbox-handle"></div>
  <input class="checkbox-input w-checkbox-input" data-name="Checkbox" id="checkbox" name="checkbox" type="checkbox">
  <label class="checkbox-label w-form-label" for="checkbox"></label>
</div>

<div class="checkbox-field w-checkbox w-clearfix">
  <div class="checkbox-handle"></div>
  <input class="checkbox-input w-checkbox-input" data-name="Checkbox2" id="checkbox2" name="checkbox2" type="checkbox">
  <label class="checkbox-label w-form-label" for="checkbox"></label>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
// Checkbox
    $('#checkbox').change( function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(this).prev('.checkbox-handle').addClass('checked');
            $(this).next('.checkbox-label').addClass('checked');
        }else{
            $(this).prev('.checkbox-handle').removeClass('checked');
            $(this).next('.checkbox-label').removeClass('checked');
        }
    });

    $('#checkbox2').change( function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(this).prev('.checkbox-handle').addClass('checked');
            $(this).next('.checkbox-label').addClass('checked');
        }else{
            $(this).prev('.checkbox-handle').removeClass('checked');
            $(this).next('.checkbox-label').removeClass('checked');
        }
    });
</script>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
.checkbox-field {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
}

.checkbox-label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 35px;
  height: 15px;
  min-width: 30px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: #ededed;
  -webkit-transition: all 150ms ease-out;
  transition: all 150ms ease-out;
}

.checkbox-handle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 21px;
  height: 21px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #d6d6d6;
  -webkit-transition: all 150ms ease-out;
  transition: all 150ms ease-out;
}

.checkbox-handle.checked {
  background-color: #f50291;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translate(16px, 0px);
  -ms-transform: translate(16px, 0px);
  transform: translate(16px, 0px);
}

.checkbox-input {
  display: none;
}
.checkbox-handle{
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

I made a codepen too: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VpOMbK.

You can see that only the right one is working. I can't find out why and I've been struggling to look for it!

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: data-name="Checbox" typo? Checkbox...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is your `for="checkbox2"`

Change

```
<div class="checkbox-field w-checkbox w-clearfix">
  <div class="checkbox-handle"></div>
  <input class="checkbox-input w-checkbox-input" data-name="Checkbox2" id="checkbox2" name="checkbox2" type="checkbox">
  <label class="checkbox-label w-form-label" for="checkbox"></label>
                                                          ^missing a 2
</div>
```

to

```
<div class="checkbox-field w-checkbox w-clearfix">
  <div class="checkbox-handle"></div>
  <input class="checkbox-input w-checkbox-input" data-name="Checkbox2" id="checkbox2" name="checkbox2" type="checkbox">
  <label class="checkbox-label w-form-label" for="checkbox2"></label>
</div>
```

```js
$('#checkbox').change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(this).prev('.checkbox-handle').addClass('checked');
    $(this).next('.checkbox-label').addClass('checked');
  } else {
    $(this).prev('.checkbox-handle').removeClass('checked');
    $(this).next('.checkbox-label').removeClass('checked');
  }
});

$('#checkbox2').change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(this).prev('.checkbox-handle').addClass('checked');
    $(this).next('.checkbox-label').addClass('checked');
  } else {
    $(this).prev('.checkbox-handle').removeClass('checked');
    $(this).next('.checkbox-label').removeClass('checked');
  }
});
```

```css
.checkbox-field {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
}

.checkbox-label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 35px;
  height: 15px;
  min-width: 30px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: #ededed;
  -webkit-transition: all 150ms ease-out;
  transition: all 150ms ease-out;
}

.checkbox-handle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 21px;
  height: 21px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #d6d6d6;
  -webkit-transition: all 150ms ease-out;
  transition: all 150ms ease-out;
}

.checkbox-handle.checked {
  background-color: #f50291;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translate(16px, 0px);
  -ms-transform: translate(16px, 0px);
  transform: translate(16px, 0px);
}

.checkbox-input {
  display: none;
}

.checkbox-handle {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<div class="checkbox-field w-checkbox w-clearfix">
  <div class="checkbox-handle"></div>
  <input class="checkbox-input w-checkbox-input" data-name="Checkbox" id="checkbox" name="checkbox" type="checkbox">
  <label class="checkbox-label w-form-label" for="checkbox"></label>
</div>

<div class="checkbox-field w-checkbox w-clearfix">
  <div class="checkbox-handle"></div>
  <input class="checkbox-input w-checkbox-input" data-name="Checkbox2" id="checkbox2" name="checkbox2" type="checkbox">
  <label class="checkbox-label w-form-label" for="checkbox2"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: You forgot a { on line 78, gonna try it

Comment: @Nathanael Corrected the snippet, hope it helps you

Comment: @Nathanael Happy to help